# Testing Like button within internal network

Tags: facebook, api

I am developing a webapp that has Like and Send buttons on a page.  When I click Like, I get the dialog to add comments and the Like count increases by one after the dialog is closed, however, the Facebook user's wall/timeline doesn't show that the Like happened.  Send button just displays a popup with 'The page at *MyServerURL* could not be reached.".

I am doing this within an internal, private network behind a company firewall.  Doing the same thing on an Internet-facing test server (i.e. accessible from the Internet) works fine.

So my question is, in order for a Like to appear on the user's timeline and the Send button to work, does Facebook need to be able to directly connect to my server?

Someone else wrote the code, so I'm not sure if this is helps.  Confidential text has been removed.

---

```
<iframe id="f3712ac8730a7ce" class="fb_ltr" scrolling="no" name="f83eb0490c4d7e" style="border: medium none; overflow: hidden; height: 20px; width: 126px;" title="Like this content on Facebook." src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?api_key=336898076326008&locale=en_US&sdk=joey&ref=%2B11604%2B%2B&channel_url=http%3A%2F%2Fstatic.ak.facebook.com%2Fconnect%2Fxd_arbiter.php%3Fversion%3D17%23cb%3Df1506af703597fe%26origin%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252FserverURL%252Ff19ab39215d694e%26domain%3DserverURL%26relation%3Dparent.parent&href=http%3A%2F%2FserverURL&node_type=link&width=150&layout=button_count&colorscheme=light&action=like&show_faces=false&send=true&extended_social_context=false">


<form id="u5mamr22" onsubmit="return window.Event && Event.__inlineSubmit && Event.__inlineSubmit(this,event)" action="/plugins/like/connect" method="post" ajaxify="/plugins/like/connect" rel="async">
<input type="hidden" autocomplete="off" value="AQAUDubM" name="fb_dtsg">
<input type="hidden" value="http://serverURL" name="href" autocomplete="off">
<input type="hidden" value="like" name="action" autocomplete="off">
<input type="hidden" name="nobootload" autocomplete="off">
<input type="hidden" value="http://serverURL" name="iframe_referer" autocomplete="off">
<input type="hidden" value="+11604++" name="ref" autocomplete="off">
<div class="pluginConnectButton">
<div class="pluginButton pluginButtonSmall pluginButtonInline pluginConnectButtonDisconnected" title="">
<div>
<button type="submit">
<i class="pluginButtonIcon img sp_like-send sx_like-send_fav"></i>
Like
</button>
</div>
</div>
<div class="pluginButton pluginButtonSmall pluginButtonPressed pluginButtonInline pluginButtonX pluginConnectButtonConnected hidden_elem" title="">
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: what language are you using?  We need to see your code...

Answer (score 0):

Like Buttons only work if the link to be liked is public, so you cannot just like something on your internal network. It has to be reachable for Facebook.

Comment: Thanks.  One of my testers claimed it worked before with an internal test server.  Any idea whether this behavior has always been like this or a change in the past year caused this?

Comment: At least in the last 1-2 years it was like this :) - Maybe it was a small bug. Facebook does have some of those from time to time...